# Custom Domain Github Pages

Tags: github, dns

So I've followed the [directions](https://help.github.com/articles/setting-up-a-custom-domain-with-github-pages/) for setting up a [custom domain](https://help.github.com/articles/tips-for-configuring-a-cname-record-with-your-dns-provider/) with Github Pages. As per their [recommendation](https://help.github.com/articles/about-custom-domains-for-github-pages-sites/#subdomains), I'm attempting to set this up using a custom subdomain.

I purchased my domain through GoDaddy, and using their DNS Manager tool I added myappname.github.io under Host (CNAME):

[image]

I didn't change anything else, such as that IP address under A (Host).

Lastly, on my Github page when I go under settings it correctly says "Your site is published under www.myappname.com"

Yet, when I go to www.myappname.com, I see the following:

[image]

What did I do wrong?

**Edit:**

Output from dig:

```
dig www.myappname.co

; <<>> DiG 9.8.3-P1 <<>> www.myappname.co
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19874
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 3, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.myappname.co.      IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.myappname.co.   3600    IN  CNAME   myappname.github.io.
myappname.github.io.    3600    IN  CNAME   github.map.fastly.net.
github.map.fastly.net.  18  IN  A   199.27.76.133

;; Query time: 198 msec
;; SERVER: 10.2.0.4#53(10.2.0.4)
;; WHEN: Tue Mar 17 11:08:00 2015
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 120
```

Comment: How long did you wait after changing your DNS settings? DNS changes take time to propagate. Also, you're not actually using `myappname.github.io` and `www.myappname.com`, right? You're using a real repository and domain?

Comment: Changed it at around 12am today (so last night). And yes I'm using a real name haha

Comment: Could you try an IP lookup for `www.myappname.com` using `dig` on Linux or OSX, or `nslookup` on Windows and add the output to your question?

Comment: @Chris yup, edited my question

Comment: 1. If you visit `www.myappname.com` with dev tools enabled and look at the `Server` response header does it show GitHub.com? 2. What happens when you visit `myappname.github.io` directly? 3. Are you willing to link to the GitHub repository in question (I'm guessing not, since you've used `myappname` so consistently).

Comment: @Chris oh sure, it's really not that big a deal. thundrapp.github.io

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73177/discussion-between-chris-and-apollo).

Comment: @Chris the chat function seems to be a bit buggy on mobile. Are you suggesting that I need to add an A record in addition to the CNAME? And unfortunately I'm not sure about the value for that. Also yes I'm aware of Github not supporting backend scripts thank you.

Comment: Not necessarily. I'm suggesting that there are multiple issues at play. Will you able to log into Stack Overflow on a non-mobile device later and participate in the chat? It's likely easiest to have a synchronous discussion.

Comment: @Chris yes does 2pm EST (so in about an hour and a half) today work for you? Very kind of you to offer to do this. Thank you.

Comment: I should be online then. Just pop into the chat following the link above.

Comment: @Chris online now, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your DNS is configured to redirect the `www` subdomain to your GitHub Pages site, but your GitHub Pages `CNAME` file specifies that your application should run on the apex domain, `myappname.com`. This causes another redirection to the apex domain, which as you point out in your question has its own `A` record pointing to a non-GitHub IP address.

As we discussed, one possible solution is to update the `CNAME` file in your repository to use `www.myappname.com` instead of `myappname.com` and then set up a redirect from the apex domain to the `www` subdomain.

This will cause requests to `myappname.github.io` and `myappname.com` to redirect to `www.myappname.com`, where your site lives.