# Jekyll, Github pages + Custom domain failure

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

I have just tried adding a custom domain to my Github page but now I have a message that says

> '404: There isn't a GitHub Pages site here.'

If I build the page site locally all works as expected. So presumably I have not redirected the webpage correctly? How would I confirm this? I thought the problem may be the same as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29099398/custom-domain-github-pages) but I don't *think* it is, since removing or adding www does not change anything.

I have not received any errors from Jekyll and have no clue where to look for what is going wrong.

Any advice someone might have for fixing or identifying where to look would be greatly appreciated.

The custom domain is [sampassmore.com](http://sampassmore.com) and the build of my website can be found [here](https://github.com/SamPassmore/SamPassmore.github.io)

Comment: It is working, domain systems take a while to propagate changes

Answer (score 0):

I can observe CNAME record used, there is this [trobuleshooting guide](https://help.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-custom-domains/#dns-configuration-errors).

But **first make sure that it does not require GitHub enterprise**